# How can I read the texture data so I can edit it?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm using OpenGL and I've defined a texture in a framebuffer object with the following lines of code :

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &ssaoFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFBO);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE27);
glGenTextures(1, &ssaoTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WG, WG, 0, GL_RGBA, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    ssaoTexture, 0);

glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

In the end I want to apply anti-aliasing to my texture. In order to do that it would be very helpful if I had the pixel data in an array.

How can I read the texture and place its data in an array? I think the function `glGetBufferSubData` might be helpful but I can't find a tutorial with a full example to use it properly.

Also, when I do edit the array, how can I put the new data in my texture?

Update:
If anyone else is having issues, this is how it worked for me :

```
std::vector<GLubyte> pixels(1024* 1024* 4);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE27);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoTexture);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data()); 
// Now pixels vector contains the pixel data

//...
//Pixel editing goes here...
//...

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WG, WG, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        &pixels[0]); //Sending the updated pixels to the texture
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 It still doesn't work. I think you already know this, but the texture gets ruined when glTexImage2D is executed. I'll try the code you posted below.

Comment: Did the loading of the pixel data (`glGetTexImage`) work?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think yes, but I'm not sure. The array seems to be getting values but of course I can't check if they are correct. That's why I'm trying to send the array data back to the texture.

Comment: @Rabbid76 All good now. The vector solution you gave made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've 2 possibilities. The texture is attached to a framebuffer. Either read the pixels from the framebuffer or read the texture image from the texture.

The pixels of the framebuffer can be read by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml). Bind the framebuffer for reading and read the pixels:

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFBO);
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, format, type, pixels);
```

The texture image can be read by [`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml). Bind the texture and read the data:

```cpp
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoTexture);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, type, pixels);
```

---

In both cases `format` and `type` define the pixel format of the target data.
e.g. If you want to store the pixels to an buffer with 4 color channels which 1 byte for each channel then `format = GL_RGBA` and `type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.
The size of the target buffer has to be `widht * height * 4`.

e.g.

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
int width = ...;
int height = ...;
std::vector<GLbyte> pixels(width * height * 4); // 4 because of RGBA * 1 byte

glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data());
```

or

```cpp
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data());
```

---

Note, if the size in bytes of 1 row of the image, is not dividable by 4, then the [`GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter has to be set, to adapt the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row.

e.g. for an tightly packed `GL_RGB` image:

```cpp
int width = ...;
int height = ...;
std::vector<GLbyte> pixels(width * height * 3); // 3 because of RGB * 1 byte

glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels.data());
```